# Booting problem with my Ubuntu 10.4

Tags: boot

When I start my Ubuntu desktop version it shows `Target file system doesn't have /sbin/init`.

How can I resolve that problem?

It starts with initramfs.

Pls solve my problem as soon as possible

Comment: Close-flaggers (and any future close voters): Ordinarily we'd close this as it's a new question about an EoL release (Ubuntu 10.04 is EoL for desktops). But there is an answer that appears correct, and the answer has an upvote. Since this is not an unanswered question, there is *probably* no reason to close it. **abhisheksharma**: You shouldn't use 10.04 on a desktop system; only bare bones server packages are still supported (main and restricted components, minus any packages that provide or rely on a GUI). Other parts of the OS don't get updates for newly discovered security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search came up with [this](http://pinoy-computing-tips.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-fix-ubuntu-error-no-init-found.html) and it looks like your problem with the given info.
As the site describes;

1. Boot from the Ubuntu Live CD;
2. Open/Run Terminal;
3. Type: sudo fdisk -l (to get the device name) then press ENTER
4. Type: sudo fsck /dev/sda1 then press ENTER;
5. Restart the system and boot normally.